# how to lock free use two ConcurrentHashMap in java/scala?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrenthashmap

I headache with the problem long time ago, hope some help really.
I want store many `Task` with `ConcurrentSkipListMap` which inner is  `ConcurrentHashMap` as known as multi-segment lock.
The simple example code show with scala(java also readable):
`val tasks = new ConcurrentSkipListMap[TaskKey, Task]()`
refer class simple as:

`class TaskKey(id: String, systemTime: Long)`
TaskKey class used to identity Task is unique and the Task as follow:

```
trait Task {
  val taskId: TaskKey //account and custom name
  def execute(): Unit //do the task
}
```

When I use TaskKey to operate my HashMap is grate but actually, the HashMap can access with id barely.So, I must define another ConcurrentHashMap to store map of id to TaskKey:
`val auxiliaryMap = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, TaskKey]()`
Let's consider a add and remove operate:

```
def get(taskId: String) = {
  Option(auxiliaryMap.get(taskId)).flatMap{x => //try get TaskKey
    //if TaskKey exist, try get it.
    Option(tasks.get(x)) //make null to None
  }
}

def remove(taskId: String) = {
  Option(auxiliaryMap.remove(taskId)).flatMap{ x => //try get TaskKey
    //if TaskKey exist, try remove it.
    Option(tasks.remove(x)) //make null to None
  }
}
```

***Obviously, although both of Map is thread safe, the wrapper make data not consistency.*** If I use a lock the multi-segment Map become meaningless. How can I deal with the problem make two ConcurrentHashMap work well?

Besides, the TaskKey contains a systemTime variable used to sort data,complete `ConcurrentSkipListMap` define as this:

```
val tasks = new ConcurrentSkipListMap[TaskKey, Task](new Comparator[TaskKey]() {
  override def compare(o1: TaskKey, o2: TaskKey): Int = {
    val compare = (o1.systemTime - o2.systemTime).toInt

    if (compare == 0) {
      o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode()
    } else compare //distinct same time task
  }
})
```

any question are welcome if I miss something.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by *When I use TaskKey to operate my HashMap is great but actually, the HashMap can access with id barely.*? There are some approaches to synchronise 2 hashmaps, but it's always better to have all in just one as you suggested initially.

Comment: @Augusto, `get(taskId: String)` used to get a `Task` object.I must get `TaskKey` before get `Task`.*barely* means I can't use `TaskKey` straightly and only can get data with a taskId string.That's why I'm use two HashMap.

Comment: I hate such comments myself, but I can't help to ask. Are you sure you need task id as a String. Maybe just use TaskKey as task id and have only one map?

Comment: @ArtemMalinko, your are very careful,thanks notice this.But I can't simple use TaskKey. At the situation, I simplify some logic what I want to do. For short, there are a `cancel(id: String)` operation to decide remove a task but Task has a `nextTask` method can generate new task when it was done.The new task with different TaskKey which has same `id` and different `systemTime`. In order to support cancel the generated task, older TaskKey is meaningless.So, id is the unique mark for a task in term of API user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using message queue to flatten the operator to these maps.besides,this way  needn't concurrenthashmap at all but message queue maybe need a concurrentqueue.